# unable to load symbol table with windbg

Tags: c, windbg, symbols

Newbie question when trying to debug a enterprise level executable. The c code is compiled using the following option

```
        icl.exe /nologo /MTd /W3 /Gm /GX /Zi /Od /D "WIN64" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /Fp".\win64\debug\setup.pch" /YX /Fo".\win64\debug\\" /Fd".\win64\debug\\" /c ..\c\runInstaller.c
```

I have added a `DebugBreak()` in the code to perform a hard - break point when the executable is loaded into windbg. I am able to load the source file, but unable to watch any of the variables.

The Symbol path looks like this; points to the pdb file and the microsoft symbols as well

`0:000> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\debug
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\debug`

When I try the following

```
!sym noisy
.reload
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg/573C41C963000/image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg not found
DBGHELP: c:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\debug\image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\debug\.exe\image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: c:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\debug\symbols\.exe\image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: C:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\.exe\image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: C:\oii\oiib\bin\win64\symbols\.exe\image00000001`3f2d0000.dbg - path not found
```

Do I have to generate the symbols in any other way ?  Also I am unable to watch any of the variables/set breakpoints in the code. I am suspecting that I am missing something vital here.

Edited the symbol paths

Comment: It's weird that the local path to your symbols is different in the expanded symbol path.

Comment: @MarcSherman I have manually edited some of the paths to shorten them when I  posted the query, I had updated the correct paths.

Comment: Looks like icl.exe is the Intel compiler/linker. I don't have any experience with how it generates symbols.

Comment: google says icl upto v11 didnt create a renamed pdb file with /Fd switch and was fixed in some version > 12   the dbghelp messages doesnt even look for a pdb and showing cannot fetch pdb  files so does the xxx.pdb exist for xxx.exe ?  at the given path ? does a DebugDirectory Exist in the executables PEHeader and does it point to a pdb path

Comment: You say a PDB was generated, but the debugger looks for DBG files only. Is it really this way? I never managed to get good results from DBG files.

Comment: It seemed like the pdb file was actually not being generated properly, once the pdb file was generated and the path pointed to correctly I got this working but looks like the pdb file did not have any private symbols in it which is still not very helpful